# can one ask a question one came up with oneself and one knows the answer to

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I recently did so on mathematics site, and, someone kindly commented: "why do you ask if you know?".

I am rather new here and I certainly try to behave like a good citizen. In fact, I asked the question only to contribute to this great mathematics site with a recreational humble own brew mathematical puzzle, and, agreed, the mathematical question was written as puzzle.

I was kindly suggested to perhaps ask the question on the puzzle site instead. However, maybe someone will rightly react same way as on mathematics site ... or do different sites have different etiquette ?

So question:

"can one (*yes/no*) ask a question one came up with oneself and one knows the answer to?"

I sincerely want to avoid bad practice on mathematics site and on other sites.

Have a nice day

Comment: If the goal is to provide a puzzle for others to solve, [puzzling.se] is much more appropriate.  If, on the other hand, you are posting the question in order to share some useful knowledge, then it is appropriate to post both a question and answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson OK ! I will try there

Comment: Thanks for checking about site policies and standards. We appreciate the courtesy.

Comment: Also, If you are pursuing the latter option Xander mentions, we expect questions, in all cases, provide context.  Do not copy an exercise into a question field, with no additional context, then immediately answer the question.

Comment: I thank you for wanting to avoid bad practice and asking this question. It was the Squid game one, right? Yeah, I thought it was off-topic but it was bountied so I couldn't do much about it for the moment. Maybe we will migrate it sometime. Have a nice day as well!

Comment: I should try and answer my own Goldbach questions probably.

Comment: You could browse a bit through the questions tagged ([meta-tag:self-answer]) to see the previous discussion on meta related to this topic.

Comment: @MartinSleziak OK ! I did not know about the self-answer tag. Sorry again for clumsyness.

Comment: For the interested, question is https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112210/how-many-mathletic-couples-were-having-dinner-at-the-table and got solved fast.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon : just FYI, it was not the 'Squid game' one (which is still there). It was the 'mathletics' one (which I deleted and recreated as puzzle 112210).

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Thanks for the clarification.