# Posting 'Solved' Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

I recently created a nice olympiad problem on the invariance principle, and I thought about posting it on Math Stack Exchange. However, I was unsure about it as the community guidelines have not mentioned anything about questions that we have already solved.

This has happened in many other cases, too. Whenever I've solved a really beautiful problem, I have wanted to post the problem and its solution on Math Stack Exchange for other users who might like the problem, and who may post their own solutions to it. However, since this wouldn't exactly be a question, are we allowed to post such questions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I added the [tag:self-answer] tag. From the tag I found related posts: [can one ask a question one came up with oneself and one knows the answer to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34206/), [Has it become too hard to write self-answered questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32671/), [Is self answering own questions a frowned upon practice in math-stack exchange?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32467) and links therein. In particular rules (like the EoQS) that apply to other questions also apply here

Comment: If someone has a great math insight to share with the world, often the best way to share it is to ask and answer their own high quality question on math.stackexchange. A blog post won't get many views (unless you happen to have a big audience). Even a book won't usually reach many people (and to share a particular insight, it doesn't make sense to write a book).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[The FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) is pretty clear on this.

> ## Yes!
>
> There are already numerous posts that answer their own questions.
> There's nothing wrong with it. It's even been encouraged since the very beginning of time.

You can see there is an option to answer your own question, and in fact, the capability to write *and post* the answer *at the same time* as the question.

This is not just allowed, but encouraged by the guidance and facilitated by the system.

If the question is good enough to be asked, and your answer is good enough to resolve that, go for it!

Comment: Oh, I thought those rules might not apply for Math Stack Exchange. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: In Math.SE the bar has been raised. Basically because otherwise we would get a lot of crap. See the earlier discussions on this theme. Not taking a position whether the question/answer pair the OP had in mind would still be ok. We simply think this position is too sweeping to serve the site well.

Comment: And as the links provided by Calvin Khor clarify, while this tool is perfectly valid on Math SE just like the rest of the network, it goes without saying that the question and answer both still need to be on-topic and meet the standards expected. I don't see anywhere that this is contradicted.

Comment: As a follow up to @JyrkiLahtonen 's comment, I'll mention that I tend to not give upvotes to self-answered questions, because of that risk of people exploiting them to merely build reputation. It sounds like the OP is one of those people who would participate here even without the reputation gamification (my preferred type, honestly), but just be aware that such posts don't fit the gamification track as well as others might.

Comment: I would say that it is encouraged, but there have been a few users who almost never interacted outside of asking questions or asking and answering their own questions (i.e. never or rarely answering other's questions or otherwise interacting with others' questions), treating MSE as a *de facto* blog. As long as you don't go overboard with ask+answer, you'll be in good standing in the community.

Comment: What about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452042/if-an-element-in-a-banach-algebra-is-anihilated-by-an-analytic-function-then-it. Ignore the question but please read the PS at the end.

Comment: That PS is unhelpful and unnecessary. Flag the post (or any post) for a moderator. @Ruy.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestions. I will make sure to rarely post such questions and only if the question is 'really' that good.

Answer (score 8):

I approve of (and have used) the approach: "I know a solution to the following question.  I would be interested in seeing other solutions.  If necessary, I will post my solution after enough time has passed."  I am less enthusiastic about cases where the answer is posted immediately.

See [Is it okay to ask mathematical puzzles and problems I have solved?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4232/442) for the agreement that this is OK.

Some of my examples: [Evaluation of a slow continued fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/368541/442) and
[Evaluation of a continued fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351333/442)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can ! I don't see why you couldn't since you have a "Answer your own question" button:
[image: Answer your own question]

Comment: This feature was added in 2012. Here is a discussion from that time: [Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4286) (Several discussions [linked to that one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4286) are about similar issues.)

Answer (score -4):

## Yes,

> *That's why there is such option*, *what's not allowed will not be allowed*,*and since you have the option, it is allowed!*

It will not only be helpfull to others, but also *change* the *reputation* as the users see it and vote.
But the *change* depends on quality of your q.s and answer : **It may be a negative or positive change!**

*In fact it will increase your rep. nearly double of what you get from your usual q.s if...*